# How to sort a dictionary by value lists numerically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Assume a Python dictionary, in which the keys are strings and the corresponding values are lists of integers.

```
> my_dict = {}
> my_dict['key1'] = [1,2,3]
> my_dict['key2'] = [4,5]
> my_dict['key3'] = [3,4,5]
> my_dict
# Python dictionaries are unordered by default
{'key2': [4, 5], 'key3': [3, 4, 5], 'key1': [1, 2, 3]}
```

What function would you write to obtain a dictionary-like object sorted by the first element of each value (i.e., first element of each list).

```
> from collections import OrderedDict
> def my_function(a_dict):
>     return OrderedDict(sorted(a_dict.items(), magic_specified_here)) # Just an example
> sorted_dict = my_function(my_dict)
> sorted_dict
{'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key3': [3, 4, 5], 'key2': [4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
return OrderedDict(sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
```

This will sort the items in the `a_dict` according to the 0th element of its values. Since `a_dict.items()` returns a tuple of `(key, value)` pairs, `x[1]` means the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` parameter `sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][0])`

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> my_dict['key1'] = [1,2,3]
>>> my_dict['key2'] = [4,5]
>>> my_dict['key3'] = [3,4,5]
>>> my_dict
{'key3': [3, 4, 5], 'key2': [4, 5], 'key1': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> my_dict.items()
dict_items([('key3', [3, 4, 5]), ('key2', [4, 5]), ('key1', [1, 2, 3])])
>>> sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][0])
[('key1', [1, 2, 3]), ('key3', [3, 4, 5]), ('key2', [4, 5])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

```
def my_function(a_dict):
     return OrderedDict(sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
```